# What is the process of requesting collected personal information for a major company online?

Tags: privacy, data-ownership

Recently I took a personal trip to a resort and theme park a large company owns in the US. As a US citizen, I have the right to request any and all personal information digitally and physically collected by this company in accordance with the Privacy Act of 1974. The reason for my request is simple curiosity about the data collected, and how identifying it actually is, as well as simply seeing how much and what they have collected. [This site](https://www.archives.gov/about/laws/privacy-act-1974.html#page-header) discusses what appears to be a long legal process in making the request. So,

1. Do I need a lawyer for this?
2. **What is the overall process for me, as a legal US adult citizen, in requesting all physically and digitally collected information from a very large and physically distant business after using their services a short time ago?**

EDIT:
    For anyone coming here in the future: the information in my question is incorrect. This is not what the Act is talking about. Please see the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the Privacy Act of 1974, you have the right to request any and all personal information in the possession of *federal agencies*. The Act gives you no such right with private companies.

You could kindly ask the company to provide this information, but they are under no obligation to provide it (and have very good reasons not to).

Comment: So you're saying that any company can collect any information they want, and then they don't need to give me my own information back?

Comment: its not yours. Its theirs. Its facts about you they collected.